How to set Stripe PaymentElement for saving cards
I am struggling with setting up the Stripe payment element. I am creating a Payment element by passing setupIntent. When a user clicks on the "submit" button, I am calling confirmSetup() to save card information from the element to Stripe.
I have 3 questions here-
a) The payment element UI is displaying additional fields. I have attached a screenshot below, highlighting those extra fields. How can I avoid or rectify this issue?paymentElement of stripe.
b) For a PaymentElement to accept customer details how to add Name on card field.
c) How can I avoid duplicate card additions for a customer? Before confirming setupIntenet, how can I check if the card entered in the payment element already exists or not?
I tried below code-
<script setup lang="ts">
let setupIntent = getSetupIntent(stripeCustomerId);
const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
};

const options = {
    clientSecret: setupIntent.clientsecret,
    appearance,
};

elements = stripe.elements(options);
const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
paymentElement.mount("#payment-element"); 

const confirmSetup = async() => {
    const result = await stripe.confirmSetup({
        elements,
        redirect: "if_required"
    });
}
</script>

<html>
<div>
    <form id="payment-form">
        <div id="payment-element"></div>
        <div id="payment-message"></div>
    </form>
    <button onclick="confirmSetup()">Submit</button>
</div>
</html>


a) What you highlighted in your screenshot is called LINK a Stripe provided payment method to provide faster Checkout for your customers. If you wish to disable it you can see the instructions here
b) You have 2 options here:

you can collect the Card Name with a custom input you add yourself outside of the PaymentElement, and then you pass it to the billing_details.name field when confirming your SetupIntent
or you can choose to add the AddressElement in billing mode to collect the name and address information of your customer. These will be automatically collected and added to the PaymentMethod once you call confirmSetup.

c) This is honestly not a straight-forward thing to do but I will give you the flow with some code but this means you migrate the way you generate your SetupIntents/PaymentMethods:

First you need to prepare your PaymentElement to create confirmation tokens

const options = {
    mode: 'setup',
    currency: 'eur',
    paymentMethodCreation: 'manual',
    setupFutureUsage: 'off_session',
    appearance,
};

elements = stripe.elements(options);


instead of calling confirmSetup on your button click, you call the following method

const handleSubmit = async (event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {error: submitError} = await elements.submit();
    if (submitError) {
      handleError(submitError);
      return;
    }
    const {error, confirmationToken} = await stripe.createConfirmationToken({elements});

    if (error) {
      handleError(error);
      return;
    }
    
};


Call your backend to create a SetupIntent

const handleSubmit = async (event)=> {
    //everything from step 2
    ...
    const {error:setupError, client_secret} = await getSetupIntent(stripeCustomerId, confirmationToken.id);
    if (setupError) {
      handleError(setupError);
      return;
    }
};


When you're creating the SetupIntent on your backend you will do the following:


retrieve the confirmation token
look at the fingerprint
list all customer's card payment methods
check whether any other payment method has the same fingerprint
If there's a duplicate return an error to the frontend
Else create a SetupIntent and return the client_secret to the frontend for confirmation


Confirm the SetupIntent

const handleSubmit = async (event)=> {
    //everything from step 3
    ...
    const {error:confirmError} = await stripe.confirmSetup({
      clientSecret,
      confirmParams: {
        confirmation_token: confirmationToken.id,
        return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
      },
    });

    if (confirmError) {
      handleError(confirmError);
    }
};

I know this is complicated but you can refer to this doc for more details.
